# React app call to localhost node server on hostedVM

Tags: reactjs, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I'm serving a built react file using `Nginx`. I am able to access the react app in the browser on my vm's IP address.

I have another server running on my VM on port `8080`, the API of the react app.

In my react I use axios calls like

```
const http = "http://localhost:8080";
..
axios.post(`${http}/api/auth/login`, { credentials }).then(res => res.data.user),
```

In my browser after I access my VM's ip address I can see in the console that the so called axios calls go to `http://myActualVMIpAddress/api/..` instead of the `localhost` path as I was expecting.

I have checked the routes using `postman` of the api server.

I don't have experience with deployment. How do I make the link between the react app and the api server to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to hard code localhost:8080 into your client JS, when your user loads the client files they will try and make a request on your users computer which is what localhost resolves to.

Easiest is to serve your client files from your api server. If you want to keep these separate then you have to use the IP of your API server (not localhost) and setup CORS.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to develop them separate from the start in case I want to run the api on a vm and the website on another. I guess that I could for start just serve the react compiled file using the api server on any other route that doesn't begin with `/api/` and use `nginx` to reroute to `8080` or straight run the server on port `80`. Does this sound appropriate in this situation?

Comment: Yes you could use nginx as a proxy and route requests to /api on port 80 to your api server on the local machine at whatever port you want quite easily.